# Finding all numbers in a text and returning them in a list of floats in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, analysis

I have extracts of text, and need to create a function that finds all numbers in the text and returns them in a list of floats.

It would be great if commas could be used to separate thousands and several consecutive numbers could be separated by a comma and space

```
E.g., extract_numbers("12 days of XMas") is [12.0]
E.g., extract_numbers("1, 2, 3, un pasito pa'lante Maria")
is [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

:param text: string that forms English text
:return: list of numbers (as floats) that are present in the text
:rtype: list
```

```
  #Variable for storing the sum 
a = 0
  
 #Iterating through the content 
 #Of the file 
for line in content: 
      for i in line: 
          
        # Checking for the digit in  
        # the string 
        if i.isdigit() == True: 
              
            a += int(i) 
  
[float(i) for i in a]
print("The sum is:", a)
```

Unfortunately I am receiving a TypeError :

`'int' object is not iterable' at '[float(i) for i in a]'`

Answer (score 1):

`a` is int and it's not iterable. You can use this:

```
a = 0
floats = []  
for line in content: 
      for i in line: 
        if i.isdigit() == True:              
            a += int(i) 
            floats.append(float(i))
```

Now `floats` is a list that contains all of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your `extract_numbers` function may look like this using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

def extract_numbers(line):
  return [float(num) for num in re.findall(r'\d+', line)]
```

Then you may do the following:

```
# Variable for storing the sum 
a = 0

# Iterating through the content of the file 
for line in content: 
    a += extract_numbers(line)

print("The sum is:", a)
```